# Querying relationships of relationships in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a query in Rails but am having some trouble creating the correct one.  Below is my models with their relationships.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :rsvps, class_name: 'Event'
  has_many :albums
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_and_belongs_to_many :attendees, class_name: 'User'
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

I need to get all events a user has "rsvp'ed" to that they haven't uploaded an album to yet.  I can find out if a user has uploaded an album to a particular event using the following:

```
u = User.find(1)
e = Event.find(1)
e.albums.where(user_id: u.id)
```

I want to be able to run this query on each of the user's rsvp'ed albums.  I know I could do something like this:

```
u.rsvps.delete_if { |e| !e.albums.where(user_id: u.id).blank? }
```

However, I want to do this all in one query instead of getting the rsvps and then iterating over them and deleting them when necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get all events a user has rsvp'ed to but haven't uploaded an album to yet, you can use the following, which (**UPDATE**) now also works when a user has not uploaded any albums.

```
@event_ids = Album.where(user_id: u.id).pluck(:event_id))
@event_ids.empty? ? u.rsvps : u.rsvps.where("id not in (?)", @event_ids)
```

In addition, this query should work as well.

```
u.rsvps.where.not(id: Album.where(user_id: u.id).pluck(:event_id))
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I'm looking for a way to get the events they are rsvp'ed to that they haven't uploaded an album for. I don't care about the albums themselves for now.

Comment: Oh shoot, sorry about that, I totally misread the question. I updated my answer with a solution that should work for what you are actually looking for.

Comment: The only problem with the above is it returns an empty when `Albums.where(user_id: u.id).pluck(:event_id)` returns an empty array.  It should return all the rsvps at that point.

Comment: Great find. The updated answer should work for a user with no uploaded albums now.